# How do I chain nested promises with Q? I can't get them to run in proper order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I want to be able to chain together methods which themselves may include chained methods.

The log should read "first, second, third". However, in practice it comes out "second, third, first".

I know this code is a bit redundant, but I'm just trying to understand how promises/node executes. How would I write promise-based functions that themselves can be chained together?

```
    user.increaseReadings(id)
      .then(function(val) { console.log("second",val); return user.findById(id); })
      .then(function(val) { console.log("third",val); res.json(val); });
  }
```

From `/models/user` module:

```
exports.findById = findById;
function findById(id)  {
  deferred = Q.defer();

  User.findById(id, function(err, doc) { 
    if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
    deferred.resolve(doc);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

exports.increaseReadings = increaseReadings;
function increaseReadings(id) {
  deferred = Q.defer();

  findById(id).then(function(doc) {     <-- here's the problem
    doc.readings++;
    doc.save(function(err, doc) { 
      console.log("first");
      if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
      deferred.resolve(doc);
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite your increaseReadings as such:

```
function increaseReadings(id) {
    return findById(id).then(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        doc.readings++;
        doc.save(function(err, doc) { 
            console.log("first");
            if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
            deferred.resolve(doc);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

The important difference between this code and the one you wrote is that the anonymous function passed to the 'then' method returns a promise.

In most promise implementations, if you return a promise as a result of a handler, the next step in the chain will not execute until you resolve that promise you returned.